# c# combobox autocomplete like method

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, combobox

I have been looking for an LIKE `autocompletion` mode. Can anyone help me with this.

When I enter a text in the `ComboBox`, the database should be asked for the data. 
all that goes well.
But then I want my `ComboBox` to behave like the Suggest mode, but it doesn't work.

I tried this:

```
cursorPosition = txtNaam.SelectionStart;
string query = "SELECT bedr_naam FROM tblbedrijf WHERE bedr_naam LIKE '%" + txtNaam.Text + "%'";
DataTable table = Global.db.Select(query);
txtNaam.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    txtNaam.Items.Add(table.Rows[i][0].ToString());
}
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

txtNaam.Select(cursorPosition, 0);
```

But the behavior that this function creates is off it doesnt work like the suggest mode its a bit buggy.

Can anyone help me to get it working properly.

Comment: What is `txtNaam` in your code? Are you in [tag:winforms] or [tag:asp.net]?

Comment: WinForms sorry, And the txtNaam is the name of the combobox... Iknow its off.

Comment: You could use a DataView on the textchanged event perhaps? that re-shapes your combobox datasource?

Comment: Getting the data in the combobox is not the problem, I want the behavior of AutoCompletionMode Suggest only then with the LIKE operator

Answer (score -1):

I may have this concept incorrect but you could do this on the `TextChanged` Event :-

```
DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "SearchField LIKE '*" + Combobox1.Text + "*'";
```

If you have the DataTable Bound to a Binding Source, and use the Binding Source as the Datasource for your `ComboBox`, then each key press will refine the list.